# The Choice constraint expects a valid callback

Tags: forms, symfony-2.1

I updated Symfony2 to 2.1 and when I trying submit form I am getting error:

> The Choice constraint expects a valid callback

source code from form type class:

```
$builder->add('type', 'choice', 
                    array(
                        'expanded' => true, 
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'choice_list' => new TypeChoices(),
                        'required' => true,
                    )
                  )
```

TypeChoices class:

```
class TypeChoices implements ChoiceListInterface {

    public static $choices = array(
        'full-time' => 'Full time', 
        'part-time' => 'Part time', 
        'freelance'  => 'Freelance',
    );

    public static function getChoiceNameByValue($value)
    {
        return self::$choices[$value];
    }

    public function getChoices() 
    {   
        return self::$choices;  
    }

    public static function getTypeChoicesKeys() 
    {
        return array_keys(self::$choices);
    }

    public static function getPreferredChoiceKey()
    {
        return 'full-time';
    }
}
```

Could someone give me any advice?

Comment: The implementation of `ChoiceList` seems to have been changed. Did you take look at [`upgrade-2.1.md`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md#other-bc-breaks)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to extend the [SimpleChoiceList](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/ChoiceList/SimpleChoiceList.html) class, this way:

**ChoiceList code:**

```
class TypeChoices extends SimpleChoiceList
{
    public static $choices = array(
        'full-time' => 'Full time', 
        'part-time' => 'Part time', 
        'freelance'  => 'Freelance',
    );

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param array $preferredChoices Preffered choices in the list.
     */
    public function __construct(array $preferredChoices = array()) // PASS MORE ARGUMENT IF NEEDED
    {
        parent::__construct(
            static::$choices,
            $preferredChoices
        );
    }
}
```

**Form type code:**

```
->add('type', 'choice', array(
    'choice_list' => new TypeChoices(),
    ...
))
```